# Windows 10 stopped loading after one or more Ubuntu upgrades

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

On my Dell XPS15 9560 I have a dual-boot setup with Ubuntu and Windows 10. I was using Ubuntu 16 with Windows 10 for some time, booting to either OS just fine. Then I upgraded to Ubuntu 17, and was using both OS for some time just fine as well. Then I was using Ubuntu exclusively for several months, and kept it up to date all the time.

Today I needed to boot into Windows 10, and I found that when I select it from the boot menu, it shows the Win10 loading spinner for some time and then just restarts the PC. After a couple of restarts it boots into Win10 recovery menu. So I ran the boot-repair "recommended" option from Ubuntu and it didn't help.

Is there a way to fix my Windows installation without doing some kind of hard recovery?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yWZGBxdy6Y/ here is my Boot Info Summary from boot-repair.

Thanks.